# line-height issue with <li> child elements

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I am having an issue with line-height on a list item.

In a nutshell, we have a line-height assigned to the body, which the <li> obviously inherits.

If I put a <span> inside the list item and specify a font-size that's smaller than the standard body font, the <li> keeps the line-height for the document, not for what the span actually is using.

One thing to consider is that I'm very limited with what I can do with regards to the actual HTML, as this is HTML created by the ckeditor (wysiwyg) editor.  If you open that editor, create some list items and then change the font size, this is what you get:

```
<ul>
    <li><span style='font-size:8px'>Item 2 -- and some supporting text</span>
    <li><span style='font-size:8px'>Item 2 -- and some supporting text</span>
    <li><span style='font-size:8px'>Item 2 -- and some supporting text</span>
</ul>​
```

I can't really change what it  outputs, but of course we can try and use CSS rules to control it.

I put up a jsfiddle that illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/virtualpromote/pW47c/

If you know of a way to make the <li> to base its line-height on the height of the <span> within it, that would be awesome.

-- Javascipt is not an option to solve this problem. The HTML that's generated is actually passed onto an app that creates a PDF out of it on the fly, so that of course, can't parse any javascript rules that we could apply after the fact.

Comment: Not 100% sure but try adding display:block to the span elements and see if that helps.d

Comment: ADDENDUM:  Adding display:block to the span (as suggested) works great in the jsfiddle that I originally setup.  However, I forgot to put the list-style-type:disc in there for li like I have in my actual CSS.  Putting that in there screws up the li because even though it knows that the span is a tiny font, it still wants to draw a huge dot.  http://jsfiddle.net/virtualpromote/pW47c/17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John,

Billy Moat has the right idea, something like this will work:

```
li span { line-height: 10px; display:block; }​
```

The span tag falls inline with its container element, the li. Changing it to block forces it outside of inline elements, thus not inside the li line-height.

Cheers

Comment: I can set the span to display:block, but I cannot set the span's line hight specifically.  The span is auto-generated by the ckeditor (wysiwyg) so I don't know what it's going to be.  Could be anywhere from 48px to 6px.  What I need is for the li tag to "up-herit" the font-size from the span within, if that makes sens!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the line height of the list element to normal?

```
li {line-height: normal;}
```

Comment: I did try and that has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is to not add a unit to your line-height. Simply using 1.3 will keep your line-height in proportion.

Comment: Right, and the explanation is that when you set `line-height: 1.3`, then the inherited value is the pure number 1.3, and it is interpreted as relative to the font size of each element. If you use `1.3em`, then the value is computed and this value (1.3 times the copy text font size) is inherited.

Comment: If I don't define a line-height, then I'm eeing it default to "line-height:normal" when I inspect with firebug, and I get the same general issue, but with a slightly less tall spacing (remove that line and you'll see the result). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to reduce the line height by .3 so that the span is using a normal line height? If so you can do the following:

```
li {line-height: .8em;}
```

Comment: The trouble with that solution is that I don't know what the font size is going to be.  Remember the WYSIWYG editor is spitting out the span on  the fly based on a font size choice.  Happens to be inside of an li tag ... so a generic or specific line height only works when I know in advance the font size